# Tkinter dropdown menu in the middle of a label

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: Example]

New to python and I wonder how to put a dropdown menu in the middle of a tk.Label or a better method.
I will not reveal my code in fear of humiliation :)

In the photo I want to replace 'Miliseconds' with a dropdown menu.
For 'Hours' I went cheap and just left it coming after the label in the grid :P

I'm pretty unsure with my current skills

Comment: What for? Labels are for text and images. Problems with alignment on one line with text?

Comment: Can you just use a `Label` for "Convert", `OptionMenu` for *Milliseconds*, `Label` for "to" and `OptionMenu` for *Hours*?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace 'Miliseconds' with a dropdown menu

Try this in my example:

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("320x80")
        self.title('Tkinter OptionMenu Widget')

        self.languages = ('Hours', 'Seconds', 'Minutes',
                        'Kilometers', 'Miliseconds', 'Centermeters')

        self.option_var = tk.StringVar(self)

        self.create_wigets()

    def create_wigets(self):
        paddings = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

        self.label = ttk.Label(self,  text='Select your most favorite language:')
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)

        option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(
            self,
            self.option_var,
            self.languages[0],
            *self.languages,
            command=self.option_changed)

        option_menu.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)

        self.output_label = ttk.Label(self, foreground='red')
        self.output_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, **paddings)

    def option_changed(self, *args):
        self.label['text'] = f'Convert {self.option_var.get()} to:'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]